# Compiling MIT Scheme on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

When I run ./configure I receive:

configure: running /bin/bash ./configure '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
Unknown machine type: none
configure: error: ./configure failed for compiler

This is on a Lenovo laptop with 4GB of memory.
Linux shllaptop 2.6.28-15-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 18 19:25:34 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any suggestions?

Comment: you could just pickup a binary package?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just run

```
$ sudo apt-get install mit-scheme

$ sudo apt-get install mit-scheme-doc
```

that should give you all you need.

**EDIT**

I beg to differ with those who doubt the packages!

```
$ apt-cache show mit-scheme
Package: mit-scheme
Priority: optional
Section: universe/devel
Installed-Size: 18396
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Chris Hanson <cph@debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Version: 7.7.90+20090107-1.1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11), libdb4.8, libgdbm3 (>= 1.8.3), libltdl7 (>= 2.2.6b), libmcrypt4, libmhash2, libncurses5 (>= 5.6+20071006-3), libpq5 (>= 8.4~0cvs20090328), libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8k-1), libx11-6 (>= 0)
Recommends: mime-support
Suggests: mit-scheme-dbg
Filename: pool/universe/m/mit-scheme/mit-scheme_7.7.90+20090107-1.1_i386.deb
Size: 6827762
MD5sum: a0df7937123cbca16aabe3179581fce8
SHA1: bf897fd930b12af4d785423d5711d2234d0de11d
SHA256: bc2e4bfc0c760ef2195f6ebba59ecc60c2bbaacabbe0a70f0bd25d4013e55890
Description: MIT/GNU Scheme development environment
 MIT/GNU Scheme is an implementation of the Scheme programming language,
 providing an interpreter, compiler, source-code debugger, integrated
 Emacs-like editor, and a large runtime library.  MIT/GNU Scheme is best
 suited to programming large applications with a rapid development
 cycle.
 .
 This package contains the development environment.
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Comment: Because they don't exist: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/mit-scheme/download

Comment: @Arafinwe I wasn't asking for your superficial wikipedia dump, I was asking for the deb for 64-bit. See, what I'm trying to intimate here is that there is no goddamn package for 64-bit mit-scheme, so if I'm sitting at a 64-bit ubuntu I cannot, as you said when you stumbled into this here already-solved-two-year-old question, "just run (apt commands)".

Comment: jesus, calm down. just download the 32-bit binary manually then. i'm not trying to antagonize you, and i apologize if it seems that way.

Comment: The question is about how to compile MIT Scheme, not obtaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the basics -- do you have the `build-essential` package installed?

Comment: I got it to compile with etc/make-liarc.sh.  Then I got:

scheme: error while loading shared libraries: libmhash.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

which I resolved by downloading libmhash2_0.9.9-1_i386.deb, the i386 package, from http://packages.ubuntu.com and installing if with --force-architecture.

I now works.